# NetSuite: Inactive Records Are Showing In My List Fields

Tags: netsuite

I have a list field on a project/job. This field is a list contain a list of a custom record called asset.
This list show all assets, even when they are inactive. How do I stop the lists showing inactive records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the custom field, go to the Sourcing and Filtering tab, add in "Filter Using" Inactive = F (not ticked).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77yHV.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Custom Record Type Page has an option as "Show Inactives".

[image: Show Inactives Checkbox]

Unchecking this checkbox on the Asset Custom Record Page might help. Let me know.